# take indefinite inputs in python separated by newlines

Tags: python-3.x, input, indefinite

I want to take inputs separated by new lines, but i don't wan't it to take fixed amount of inputs. Then perform some action on given inputs. For more info look at [this codechef problem](https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA01/problems/TEST).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use while loop and check the value of input in each iteration

```
    input_list=[]
    value=input()
    while(value!=condition):
         value=input()
         input_list.append(value)
```